# How to obtain the config folder/file across platforms under Free Pascal/Lazarus?

Tags: cross-platform, configuration-files, freepascal, lazarus, fpc

Is there a set of functions that give you the file and/or the folder where to place an application's config?

I would like it to return the folder only and/or the file only on the appropriate place for each system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are the following:

- `GetAppConfigDir` - [wiki page](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/getappconfigdir.html)
- `GetAppConfigFile` - [wiki page](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/getappconfigfile.html)

Those functions will use the `ApplicationName` content to determine the name of the application. You can change that behaviour with the [`OnGetApplicationName`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/ongetapplicationname.html) callback.

You can have a look at what they return for each system on the [Multiplatform Programming Guide](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multiplatform_Programming_Guide) wiki page.

Comment: Two issues to be aware of: 1. These might return non-Unicode paths, so depending on your usage, you should use the *UTF8 versions of thee functions.  2. The result returned under OS X technically works but is hardly optimal for non-command-line apps.

Comment: @Noah : I've `find ... -exec grep ...` on the `fpcsrc` folder and I haven't found any UTF8 derivatives. Could you elaborate a bit more so I can update my answer? Many thanks!!